# Special characters

Tags: vbscript, character

I want to write a simple program in VBScript. In the script I enter data to a variable (string).

After a while I want to enter "\n" but instead of doing an actual \n it prints \n.

How to print special characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add it with string concatenation:

```
mystring = "stuff that comes first" & vbCrLf & "stuff that comes after"
```

Answer (score 4):

VBScript supports some constants:-

- vbLf equivalent to "\n"
- vbCr equivalent to "\r"
- vbCrLf equivalent to "\r\n"

You will need to use string concatenation to include these characters in a final string

```
Dim s
s = "First Line"
s = s & vbCrLf & "Second Line"
s = s & vbCrLf & "Third Line"
```

etc.

If you have a lot of lines this sort of concatenation can get real slow, you can switch to using the `Join` function

```
ReDim a(2)
a(0) = "First Line"
a(1) = "Second Line"
a(2) = "Third Line"

Dim s : s = Join(a, vbCrLf)
```

Answer (score 1):

the \n character in vb script is `vbcrlf` (vb carriage return line feed ).. its equivalent to \n\r.

here is a simple script.
`msgbox "Ping" & VBCRLF & "Pong"`

Comment: So how i add it to a varaible (string) ?   String str = "ZZZ" str + vbcrlf ?

Answer (score 1):

You should specify your newline using VBScript constants or the `Chr()` function:

```
What                Constant  String using Chr    Don't use this
------------------- --------- ------------------- ----------------
Carriage return     vbCr      Chr(13)             "\r"
Line feed           vbLf      Chr(10)             "\n"
CR and then LF      vbCrLf    Chr(13) & Chr(10)   "\r\n"
```

Concatenate that with the string you're trying to split over different lines.

Examples:

```
s = "First line" & vbCrLf & "Second line"
s = "First line" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "Second line"
```